# My MenuBar isn't on the top of my window?

Tags: java, javafx, menubar

Hello I want to up my menuBar on the top of the window like all sofware ?

[image]

This is the code:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Image image = new Image("GUI/Images/grass_block_side.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setFitHeight(128);
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        Button btnConvert = new Button("Convert=>");
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
        Menu fichier = new Menu("Fichier");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(fichier);
        ListView<Material> ListViewMateriel = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<Material> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
        ListViewMateriel.setItems(items);
        root.getChildren().addAll(imageView,menuBar,btnConvert,ListViewMateriel);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(15,15,15,15));
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(20);
```

Comment: It's just going to get laid out like any other component. If you put it in a `FlowPane` it will just flow along with the other controls. Usually it's best to use a `BorderPane`.

Comment: .. or in other words: learn about layouts :)

Answer (score 0):

If I could recommend using Scene Builder, everything is done there with such ease it's ridiculous. There you could anchor it to the top, left, and right, and that would do the trick. Just a recommendation

Comment: scenebuilder or not - the main point is to _understand_ what layouts are doing ;)

Comment: you are not wrong. I feel its easier to understand how layouts work in scene build but for each there own :)